# API's of the previously accessed page datatable are getting called when performing a search option on jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, angular5

In the above mentioned link, there will 2 components, i.e., Subscriber-lists and Event-registeration-list and also a helpers.ts file. We have given all the common functions inside the helpers.ts file.
The issue is that,
1) I am currently at the Subscriber-lists component and I want to access the Event-registeration module. So I clicked on the event-registeration tab. And when performing a search option in event-registeration datatable, the api of previous component that is Subscriber-list is also getting called

https://plnkr.co/edit/5smOig0HXuCbd4US?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview

please use the above link to get the full code.

```
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
    if (user.OptedPrimaryCountry == null) {
        user.OptedPrimaryCountry = "";
    }
    let perpage = 20;
    if (
        user.Details.RecordsPerPage != undefined &&
        user.Details.RecordsPerPage != null
    ) {
        perpage = user.Details.RecordsPerPage;
    }
    return {
        // datasource definition
        data: {
            type: "remote",
            source: {
                read: {
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "",
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + user.access_token,
                        "pc-id": user.OptedPrimaryCountry
                    },
                    params: {
                        query: {
                            advanceSearch: {}
                        },
                        sort: {
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: perpage,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            saveState: true,
        },
        // layout definition
        layout: {
            scroll: false,
            footer: false
        },

        // column sorting
        sortable: true,
        // order: "desc",

        pagination: true,

        toolbar: {
            // toolbar items
            items: {
                // pagination
                pagination: {
                    // page size select
                    pageSizeSelect: [10, 20, 30, 50, 100]
                }
            }
        },
        query: {
            advanceSearch: {}
        },
        sort: {
            sort: "desc",
            field: "RecordID"
        },
        search: {
            input: $("#generalSearch")
        },

        // columns definition
        columns: [
            {
                field: "RecordID",
                title: "#",
                sortable: "desc", // disable sort for this column
                selector: false
            },
            {
                field: "Actions",
                width: 110,
                title: "Actions",
                sortable: false,
                overflow: "visible",
                textAlign: "right",
                template: function(row, index, datatable) {
                    var dropup = datatable.getPageSize() - index <= 4 ? "dropup" : "";
                    if (row.IsDeleted == 0 || row.IsDeleted == undefined) {
                        return (
                            '\
                            <div class="dropdown ' +
                            dropup +
                            '">\
                                <a href="#" class="btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" data-toggle="dropdown">\
                                    <i class="la la-ellipsis-h"></i>\
                                </a>\
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">\
                                    <a class="dropdown-item edit-button" data="' +
                            row.RecordID +
                            '" ><i class="la la-edit"></i> Edit Details</a>\
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="la la-leaf"></i> Update Status</a>\
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="la la-print"></i> Generate Report</a>\
                                    </div>\
                            </div>\
                            <a id="edit-button-' +
                            row.RecordID +
                            '" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill edit-button" data="' +
                            row.RecordID +
                            '" title="Edit details">\
                                <i class="la la-edit"></i>\
                            </a>\
                            <a class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-danger m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill delete-button" data="' +
                            row.RecordID +
                            '" title="Delete">\
                                <i class="la la-trash"></i>\
                            </a>\
                        '
                        );
                    } else {
                        return (
                            '\
                            <div class="dropdown ' +
                            dropup +
                            '">\
                                <a href="#" class="btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" data-toggle="dropdown">\
                                    <i class="la la-ellipsis-h"></i>\
                                </a>\
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">\
                                    <a isdeleted="' +
                            row.IsDeleted +
                            '" class="dropdown-item restore-button" data="' +
                            row.RecordID +
                            '" ><i class="la la-user-plus"></i> Restore</a>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        '
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    };
```

Comment: Welcome. I imagine the community is going to require some code examples to provide useful feedback or direction. Can you update your question with the relevant code?

Comment: Any idea why this issue is occuring?Is the issue clear?